# Shell crossing in voids in spherical collapse model

Tags: cosmology, perturbation-theory, density, structure-formation

What would be a necessary and sufficient for shell crossing to occur in an underdense region evolving based on spherical collapse model? i.e; shells moving outward with differential acceleration?